# Opentok video capture

Tags: javascript, webrtc, opentok

Is it possible to change the video capture size?

One thing I realized is that the video size is always the same 640x360 and the ratio is 16:9.

Is that something that can be configured? (both the image size and the ratio)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not at the moment. OpenTok's webrtc archiving implementation is very new and currently in beta . It is still very basic in functionality and does not allow for adjustment for recorded video resolution.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response songz. I just noticed that the size is not always the same. Right now we are getting 640 x 480. I don't think I changed anything. Is there a parameter to switch between 16:9 to 4:3?

Comment: Are you saying that the recorded video is switching screen resolutions? It should always by recored in 4:3 ratio so 640x480 makes sense.

Comment: Oh, weird. Cuz I do remember it was at 16x9. Thanks for clarifying this.